# Align text to the right of an image && text doesn't wrap around the image

Tags: css, image

Should look like this:

```
[img] text text
      text text
```

How is this accomplished?

Seems straight forward, but I'm struggling.

Comment: stay to the right - under no circumstances should there every be wrapping!

Comment: Okay, do you know the width of your image?

Comment: Have you tried display:inline-block for both elements?  Requires an IE7 & IE6 fix if you are supporting those browsers (display:inline).

Comment: Paul, I know the width of the image.

Comment: Beth, inline-block works, how do I get it to work in IE7?

Comment: Jason has the answer - display:inline works for IE7.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `display:inline-block;`

```
img{
    display:inline-block;
    width:75px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid red;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-right:10px;
}

div{
    display:inline-block;
    width:200px;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/SK9ad/

To make `inline-block;` work with IE7, add the following to each rule:

```
zoom: 1;
*display:inline;
```

Comment: If you use this method and want to have stuff within the div then make sure to have them `display:inline-block` with `width:100%`. If this is incorrect and there is a better solution let me know. Thanks for the info though!

Answer (score 2):

Since you know the dimensions of the image:

HTML:

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <img id="theimg" ... />
    <div id="besidetheimg">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#theimg{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px; // Half the width of the image
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

#besidetheimg{
    margin-left: 100px; // width of image
}
```

It's a bit of a weird way to do it. I'm not sure if there is a better way though, and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/dvLqC/

Comment: Not that the `top` and the `margin-top` are used to vertically align the image to `middle`

Comment: Using both a negative margin, and absolute positioning is less than ideal if you can avoid it.