# CSS: how to style to make text not wrap?

Tags: css

I am doing a web application.

I am hoping to display an error message use the following html:

```
<div><i class="icon-remove-sign"></i> Error message (could take a few more lines)</div>
```

I would like to have the error message display in this "column", not wrapped under icon-remove-sign. If not using table-based design, how can I do it?

I tried different css rules, but the error text is either wrapped under icon-remove-sign or in the second line (beneath icon-remove-sign).

Thanks for help!

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question it seems like you do not want to alter your HTML code, but I am unsure if that's possible.

However, if you add a div that wraps the error message you can achieve the results you want in a couple of ways.

For example using `display: inline-block;` on both the icon and the error message:
http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/SK9ad/ (taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7005083/852765).
Be aware that inline-block has limited support in IE7 and below.

Another example using `float: left` on the icon and `margin-left` on the error message: http://jsfiddle.net/bxHnM/

Answer (score 9):

`nowrap` should do the trick:

`white-space:nowrap;`

along with a height for your `icon-remove-sign` element.

If it doesn't work, perhaps you could post the rest of your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

I know most devs ignore that as it is most often used so that elements don't go over a container but it works for text too not to wrap under an image or icon.